# Why is my page reloading on form submission?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

http://thecoxband.com/index1.html

the form works, however I am lost as to what's going on and why the ajax won't work.

I got the code from a few places up here, which I'm sure someone will link me to... but honestly I'm so new to this especially JQuery or scripting at all, so if anyone can tell me what I'm doing wrong I'd be forever in your debt.

Comment: Show us your code and markup for the form.

Comment: check your console for errors

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Samuel is correct about the JavaScript error you are getting, but you still are far from getting that form submitted.   In your script below you reference variables by the names of "email" and "name", but these variables do not exist.

```
  $(document).ready(function(){
    $('submit').click(function(){
      $.ajax({
        type:'POST',
        url: email_form.php,
        data:{
          name: name,
          email: email,
        },
        success: function(msg){
          alert('Email Sent');
        }               
      });
    });
  });
```

You need to reference the form values.   To do so you should use $('input[name="email"]').val() and $('input[name="name"]').val() respectively so the code will look like

```
  $(document).ready(function(){
    $('#submit').click(function(){
      $.ajax({
        type:'POST',
        url: 'email_form.php',
        data:{
          name: $('input[name="name"]').val(),
          email: $('input[name="email"]').val()
        },
        success: function(msg){
          alert('Email Sent');
        }               
      });
    });
  });
```

Finally I noticed one last thing, your submit button should be of the type "button" not "submit" as the latter will cause a page refresh which will break the running JavaScript.

Note I added the selector error Juan noted to the resulting function.

Comment: Thank you much, man. Now I'm getting "Uncaught ReferenceError: email_form is not defined" on the "url: email_form.php"

Comment: You need to quote it.   >    url: 'email_form.php',

Answer (score 0):

Line 93: You are declaring an object property in the global window.

```
afterLoad: function(anchorLink, index){
```

change to:

```
var afterLoad = function(anchorLink, index){
```

Answer (score 0):

I saw you had this code:

```
$('submit').click(function(){
      $.ajax({
        type:'POST',
        url: email_form.php,
        data:{
          name: name,
          email: email,
        },
        success: function(msg){
          alert('Email Sent');
        }               
      });
    });
```

That selector is wrong, change it for:

```
$('#submit').click(function(){
   //...
```

And also, you want to not only trigger on button click, but you have two options, so the form doesn't submit:

1) Listen to the submit event and prevent it to submit

```
$('#yourformid').submit(function(e){ 
    e.preventDefault(); //... })
```

2) Change your button for a `<a>` tag with a style, instead of a submit input. That way you can listen to the click event without triggering the submit.